# BotDetect Captcha with cakephp 3.6 problem

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Following the [instructions](https://captcha.com/doc/php/cakephp-captcha.html) and after loading the plugin with cakephp 3.6 ,I try to load the css with the following url:

`http://localhost:8765/captcha-handler?get=bdc-layout-stylesheet.css`

and I receive the following error:

```
Error
Not Found
Error: The requested address '/captcha-handler?get=bdc-layout-stylesheet.css' was not found on this server
```

Any idea about why the plugin is not ok installed?

I have added in `bootstrap.php`

`Plugin::load('CakeCaptcha', ['routes' => true]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using cakephp 3 and above user https://github.com/cakephp-fr/recaptcha

It is simple and easily to edit as well

I used it for all my projects and I have never faced any issues